# How can I view all of my attachments from gmail?

Tags: gmail, attachments

When I search in Gmail app for files that were attached to emails, Gmail can't find them.
Is there a way to see all of my attachments from Gmail? 3rd-party apps would be acceptable too.

Comment: Welcome to  Android Enthusiasts! Please note that recommendations like *Is there an app for X* are off-topic here (see [What topics can I ask about here?](http://android.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) for details). For where your question might fit better, you might want to look into [Where can I ask questions that aren't Android Enthusiast questions?](http://meta.android.stackexchange.com/q/371/16575). With the correct phrasing and details provided, you might try your luck at [SR](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/336/185).

Answer (score 6):

If you search for `has:attachment` within the Gmail app then you should see emails which have attachments.

Comment: If I search : file name:attachments I can find the file?

Comment: That should find the email/conversation that has the attachment with that name, yes.

Answer (score 0):

Gmail attachments (I think) are stored on the server until you download them. When you do they end up in your downloads folder on SD/flash, so you can open the folder with file manager.

Comment: I delete all my download (to save place on my phone) ..so all the attachments that I download in the past not there and when I search on Gmail I can't found them.

Answer (score -1):

you should use the new gmail INBOX + the "has:attachment" and you'll see thumbs of them all